# Fatal error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php on line 165

Tags: magento, zend-framework

I've done quite a bit of searching and have been unable to find anything out about this error.

When i try to disable the compiler in the shell like so:

```
 compiler.php disable
```

My cmd just keeps running and eventually crashes everything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've also cleared my cache and restarted the server several times. I need to figure this out.

Comment: try this, go to root/includes/config.php and comment both define statements. and then clear cache.

Comment: They were already commented out.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing rights of files. 
I was getting this error prior to chown all files.

```
chown webuser:webuser -R .
```